# Is there an advantage in adding in AngularJS after the document.ready?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at some AngularJS code that looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-class="theme">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    .... code here ....
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/cssStartup")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/cssShared")

</head>
<body>
    .... code here ....
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AngularApp")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(angular.element(document).find('body'), ['app']);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain to me if there is any advantage in having Angular added this way where it depends on the document being ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually bootstrapping angular instead of using the ng-app directive can be useful if you need to do some stuff before angular starts up (this could for example be to fetch something from the server that you want to have in place before the app is started).

In your case it is difficult to say if there is any advantage to doing this since we don't know what hides behind the ".... code here ...." blocks :)

Comment: Sorry for not including everything there. Behind the code area I have the following: <div data-ui-view="menu"></div><div data-ui-view="content"></div> and this is populated with ui-router. If I don't have the AngularJS at the bottom I am thinking it will delay the loading of the page. That's why I put it there.

Comment: I've never heard of any performance gains using manual bootstrapping. With the directive it will still bootstrap on the DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: I was meaning that maybe the page would load quicker. If I do it the other way do I need to put the script loads into the <head> area ?

Comment: No, you can (and should) still include the angular script file at the bottom of the page.